# How handle screen rotation in a ViewPager without fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-screen-support

I have a viewpager inside an activity, and an adapter connected to the viewpager which create imageview from internet.

The problem is I don't know how and where I should handle the screen rotation.

Most of topics talk about fragmentpager, but I don't use fragment.

Should I put the onsavedinstance in my ImageViewTouch class? or in the activity?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photogallery);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(url_image, list_images);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


private class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DrawableManager imagemanager;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        View view = null;

        if (list_images != null && list_images.get(position) != null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_ad_image, null);

            pos = position;

            ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) view.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            imagemanager.fetchDrawableOnThread(url_image+list_images.get(position).getHuge(), imageView);

            collection.addView(view, 0);
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this. try it.
http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html

Let me know if that helped!